# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices not showing up in Azure log streams

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, logging, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I feel like I have tried it all to get log messages shown in the Azure portal.

I have installed the relevant NuGet packages in my project:

[image: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore]

I've enabled logging in the Azure Portal.

[image]

I have added the following to my `appsettings.json`:

```
"AzureLogging": {
    "FileName": "azure-diagnostics-",
    "FileSizeLimit": 50024,
    "RetainedFileCountLimit": 5
  }
```

And the following setup code in `Startup` to be sure it had added one of them.

```
        services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options => 
        {
            options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
            options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
            options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
        });
```

The only thing I am able to get from my logs is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Startup.cs -> Configure method, you should add the following lines of code:

```
loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
loggerFactory.AddConsole();
```

Here is the code of Configure method in my Startup.cs:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //add the following 2 lines of code.
            loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();


            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

After publish to azure -> enable Application logging(Filesystem), then in Log Stream, I can see the output of logs(I set log level to verbose in my test):

[image]

Comment: Well I had added AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics but removed it again because I got notification in Visual Studio about it being deprecated and obsolete. But after adding it again per your awnser it just worked.... So much for trusting my IDE ;)

Comment: I wrote an article about that same solution adapted to .NET 5 :  https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-configure-azure-web-app-logging-with-net-5-786918eb2ff3?source=friends_link&sk=15f9fdfb96a7e8dfb294ebbe9e71a46c